# Calculating positions from four points in a realworld 3d space using pan tilt angles

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

Been trying to figure this out on and off for a couple of years thought I might just put my hand up for help.

Back story and info
Thinking in a 3D space and using theatrical moving lights (which can be pointed typically Pan 540deg and Tilt 270deg controlled by a 16bit value 0->65535 where 32767 is the center position. The angles are not the same accross different brands and models of lights.

What I need to figure out firstly is where these fixtures are in 3D Space by using four or more known points on the ground by manually pointing these fixtures at these locations and storing the pan-tilt values.

By using the known floor locations and the pan-tilt positions for each position and light would like to solve for the fixture(light) positions and rotation in space.

[Image: 3d model with fixtures and floor positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niP5Q.png)

Secondly would like to be able to use a 3D coordinate be able to point the lights to I believe using inverse kinematics but open to other methods.

Would be great if someone can point me to the correct maths to solve this.

Comment: It is not clear what is given - how 4 points are used to locate a fixture (light?)? if you have two views from two points you have 4 equations (each line two equations) and three unknowns. Do you know or can calculate a plane (such as ceiling) where the fixtures are?

Comment: Fixtures can be located anywhere in the 3d Space ie different venue locations and bar heights. So won't be able to calculate a plane of fixtures. The first process is also the calibration phase of alignment when tracking a 3D coordinate.  We know the positions of each alignment point on ground ie (-3,3,0)(3,3,0)(-3,-3,0)(3,-3,0)

Comment: What are those 4 points?

Comment: We know the positions of each alignment point on ground ie (-3,3,0)(3,3,0)(-3,-3,0)(3,-3,0) - I have used another piece of software to angles for each point for fixture at position (-5,6,-5). (-3,-3,0) = P-45 T-27 (3,-3,0) = P-76 T-56 (-3,3,0) = P-14 T-56 (3,3,0)=P-14 T-56.

Comment: Those Four points are measured marks on stage, I have attached an image to this thread they're the boxes in red - They are a tape marks that we can manually align each light

Comment: Actually two measures should suffice - the direction defines a line.